# disable recyclerview autoscroll with picasso

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso

In my fragment I have some layout with text and below that layout is a `recyclerview`. Layout for items in adapter is a single imageView in which I download an image from REST API with picasso.

The problem is that when image is loaded screen automatically scrolled to the first item in `recyclerview`, so my layout with text is not visible, and whats strange it scrolls only to the first item, not each.

In other words: you open fragment -> you see layout with text -> when images loaded screen scrolls to first image and layout now somewhere above, not visible until you manually scroll to it.

**How can I get rid of this annoying auto-scroll?**

I also have a button to load more images, and if you press on it `recycler` won`t scroll after images loaded

Here's how I load an image:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, p1: Int) {
    Picasso.get().load(array_news[p1].image).into(target(viewHolder))
    //Picasso.get().load(array_news[p1].image).into(viewHolder.itemView.news_item_image)
}

private fun target(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) = object: Target {

    override fun onBitmapLoaded(bitmap: Bitmap?, from: Picasso.LoadedFrom?) {
        if (bitmap != null) {
            val bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 400, 400, true)
            viewHolder.itemView.news_item_image.setImageBitmap(bmp)
        }
    }
    override fun onPrepareLoad(placeHolderDrawable: Drawable?) {}
    override fun onBitmapFailed(e: Exception?, errorDrawable: Drawable?) {}
}
```

Comment: Share your code or else we will have to guess what is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<LinearLayout  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Assume the `LinearLayout` which is wrapping the `RecyclerView` is your parent layout. Just add this line:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

It will prevent the focusing issue **most of the cases**, especially when the `RecyclerView` is placed in `NestedScrollView`

Comment: Thank you, that helped. I placed `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` in my parent layout (`LinearLayout` inside `NestedScrollView`).

Answer (score 0):

When the image is loaded your recyclerview just gets focus. Instead of this, when activity is opened the text view above should get focus first, not the recyclerview.
This is nothing to do with Picasso or image loading.

Go to your layout and add android:focusable = "true"  for your textView.
If this won't help, then call text_view.requestFocus() in onCreate of your activity. 
Than the text view will get the focus and the screen won't appear scrolled down to recyclerview.

Comment: Nope, didnt work.
I even tried passing view to an adapter and call requestFocus() in my target object, after setImageBitmap(bmp) function